# QNetworkReply and QNetworkAccessManager timeout in http request

Tags: c++, timeout, qnetworkaccessmanager

How do I setup a timeout when I do an http request?

I have this code:

```
{
    QNetworkRequest request;

    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.foo.com"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT.toUtf8());
    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
    request.setRawHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    reply = m_networkManager->get(request);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
}
```

Where and how do I setup some kind of timeout to the request?

Comment: I am using m_networkManager->setTransferTimeout(30000)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
QTimer timer;    
timer.setSingleShot(true);

QEventLoop loop;
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
timer.start(30000);   // 30 secs. timeout
loop.exec();

if(timer.isActive()) {
    timer.stop();
    if(m_reply->error() > 0) {
      ... // handle error
    }
    else {      
      int v = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

      if (v >= 200 && v < 300) {  // Success
        ...
      }
    }
} else {
   // timeout
   disconnect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

   reply->abort();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete the reply.

Comment: With download file process, with big file we need timeout bigger? Solution for this case?

Comment: @kienbui No. There are separate signals for this, e.g. `bytesAvailable` or `uploadProgress`

Comment: We can vote "add builtin support for network timeouts" at here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3443

Comment: this is a brilliant solution @cyber_raj

Answer (score 4):

check this out:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setTransferTimeout

> void QNetworkRequest::setTransferTimeout(int timeout =
> DefaultTransferTimeoutConstant) Sets timeout as the transfer timeout
> in milliseconds.
>
> Transfers are aborted if no bytes are transferred before the timeout
> expires. Zero means no timer is set. If no argument is provided, the
> timeout is QNetworkRequest::DefaultTransferTimeoutConstant. If this
> function is not called, the timeout is disabled and has the value
> zero.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 5.15.