# How change default connecting timeout for QNetworkAccessManager in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, connection-timeout, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I'm trying to access some url using `QNetworkAccessManager` and `QNetworkRequest`. Here is part of my code:

```
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
rep = nam->put(QNetworkRequest(myURL), myFile);
```

Sometimes it takes too long to establish the connection (because of some network related problems).
It there any way to change default connecting timeout for `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: Can't you just start a timer? Then see: if the timer fires before receiving the right signals from the reply, abort the reply; otherwise, stop the timer.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207493/qnetworkreply-and-qnetworkaccessmanager-timeout-in-http-request/13229926#13229926